# Questions about the bracket

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

In the map $\phi : L  \mapsto \mathfrak {U}(L) $, where $ L $ is a lie algebra and $\mathfrak {U} $ is a universal enveloping algebra of $ L $.

(1) Is the following relation true?

If $[xy]=z$ in $ L $, does $\phi (x) \phi (y)-\phi (y) \phi (x) = \phi (z) $?

(2) In addition if all commutators are zero in the symmetric tensor algebra of $ L $, are all brackets zero too?

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: I have to say that I don't understand any of your questions.

Comment: First question: yes. If $\phi:L\to{\cal U}(L)$ is the embedding, then $\phi([x,y]_L)=[\phi(x),\phi(y)]_{{\cal U}(L)}$. That is, the bracket in ${\cal U}(L)$ restricted to $L$ is just $L$'s original bracket. Last question: to me the symmetric algebra is an associative algebra built off of a vector space, not a lie algebra built off of a lie algebra. I am new to lie algebras, but is the symmetric algebra really considered a lie algebra in some nontrivial way as you suggest?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: Basically, if, in $ L $ $[xy]=z $, then does $\phi(x) \phi (y)-\phi (y)\phi (x)=\phi (z)$? This might be obvious. Regarding the symmetric tensor algebra, to be more specific , if all commuators are zero in the symmetric tensor algebra of $ L $ are all brackets zero? Sorry for the convoluted way of asking this.

Comment: So commutators and brackets are the same thing. The tensor algebra is not naturally a Lie algebra (except in the obvious abelian sense that comes from its assoiative algebra structure.)

Comment: @Siddharth Venkatesh: Isn't the definition of a universal enveloping algebra, an algebra where the lie algebra can be injected so the bracket becomes the commutator? I'm confused about how they are always the same. Like in the the symmetric tensor algebra there is no defined relation between the bracket and the commutator.

Comment: @dylan7 I see. You're comparing the bracket in the Lie algebra to the commutator in the associative algebra you're embedding into. That makes more sense. So, an enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is in fact an associative algebra $A$ with a Lie algebra map from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $A$. This is why brackets in the Lie algebra and commutators in the enveloping algebra coincide. You are correct that there is no relation between the Lie bracket in $\mathfrak{g}$ and the (trivial) commutator in its symmetric algebra.

Comment: @Siddharth Venkatesh: So, the brackets and commutators don't coincide in just the Lie algebra? In addition, I think I was talking to you about this in a previous post about the PBW theorem. In the graded algebra of the universal enveloping algebra, the brackets and commutators are zero. By the PBW the symmetric tensor algebra and graded algebra of the enveloping algebra are isomorphic. I know in the symmetric tensor algebra the commutators are zero, but why are the brackets zero in the symmetric tensor algebra? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am really not sure what you mean when you say there is a difference between brackets and commutators in the symmetric tensor algebra. I need to make it very clear that there is no natural map from the Lie algebra into its symmetric tensor algebra. So there is no Lie bracket in the symmetric tensor algebra that comes from the Lie algebra. There is only the trivial commutator.

Comment: My book when constructing the universal enveloping algebra used a kernel created from elements of the tensor algebra that were of the form: $x\otimes y-y\otimes x-[xy] $ if there is no bracket in the tensor algebra where did that bracket come from? I maybe confusing things.

Comment: In addition regarding the symmetric tensor and the PBW, my book said the graded algebra of the universal enveloping algebra and the sym tensor algebra are isomorphic. How can this be? The map from the tensor to the graded env algebra send commutator tensors and brackets to zero. But the sym algebra has no bracket commutator relation, so only the commuator tensors are sent to zero. Does the sym tensor algebra's trivial commutator play a part in this? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I also thought the bracket and commutators had no relation in $\mathfrak {g} $ but only became related in the enveloping algebra map, or had a relation if $\mathfrak {g} $ was a linear lie algebra. Sorry for all the questions, thank you again.

Comment: My response to your first question, is that that ideal is defined based on generators of the above form where $x, y$ are elements of the Lie algebra. That is why there is a bracket on these elements a priori. For PBW, when you take the graded algebra of the universal enveloping algebra, the algebra becomes commutative (as is the symmetric algebra). I remember trying to respond to you in a previous question about that and I might have done so incoherently or half-assedly. I'll try to construct a better response to that soon.

Comment: There is no "commutator" in a Lie algebra a priori because it is not an associative algebra (which is where the term has meaning). There is only a bracket. The enveloping algebra is an extension of the Lie algebra to an associative algebra such that the commutator of associative algebra (restricted to elements in the Lie algebra) is the same as the Lie bracket.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That makes sense. In addition, I believe I understand the whole tensor, symmetric, graded algebra of the universal issue I had now. I think my confusion was I passed over the fact that the gradation of the universal enveloping algebra removes the whole commutator bracket relation (by definition of gradation obviously) it first put in place, I.e. there is no canonical map between the eveloping algebra and its graded form.